# How to print a vector of objects from an archive in c++

Tags: c++, object, pointers, vector, printing

My code is supposed to read a file and from the information on that file create objects of class Movie and 
store them in a vector, How can I print those objects now that they are in the vector?

```
void Movie::loadFile(string file)
{
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(file+".txt");
    try {
            if (!inFile)
                throw "UNABLE TO OPEN FILE";

            }catch (const char* msg)
            {
                cerr << msg << endl;
                exit(1);
            }

    while (inFile.good())
    {
        getline(inFile, id, ',');
        getline(inFile, name, ',');
        getline(inFile, tim, ',');
        getline(inFile, gen, ',');
        getline(inFile, rate, '\n');

        mov.push_back(new Movie(id, name, tim, gen, rate));
     }
    inFile.close();
    cout<<endl;
}
```

I have tried to do it by overloading an operator but I get the errors

```
error: 'std::vector<Movie*> Movie::mov' is protected within this context
error: 'ostream_iterator' was not declared in this scope
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
```

```
ostream &operator <<(ostream& salida, const Movie& print)
{
    salida << print.id << endl;
    copy(print.mov.begin(), print.mov.end(), ostream_iterator<Video>(salida, " "));
    return salida;
}
```

I would really aprecciate the help :).

Comment: `while (inFile.good())` is similar to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use

```
copy(print.mov.begin(), print.mov.end(), ostream_iterator<Video>(salida, " "));
```

you need to implement the following overload.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Video const&);
```

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator:

> `std::ostream_iterator` is a single-pass *LegacyOutputIterator* that writes successive objects of type `T` into the `std::basic_ostream` object for which it was constructed, using `operator<<`.